# Como adicionar um icone ao botão no xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, button

Galera, eu deparei com uma coisa boba aqui mais que me deixou garrado, gostaria de colocar um ícone em um botão dentro do layout do meu aplicativo, portanto não estou conseguindo fazer, abaixo o código do meu botão... alguém poderia me dizer como fazer isso??

```
 <Button Text="Criar Chamado"
                    TextColor="White"
                    BackgroundColor="#800000"
                    Clicked="btnLogin_Clicked"
                   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade `Image` do buttons e prover um recurso disponível na sua plataforma específica. Assim:

```
<Button Text="Criar Chamado"
        TextColor="White"
        BackgroundColor="#800000"
        Image="nome_arquivo_imagem.png"   
        Clicked="btnLogin_Clicked"/>
```

*No caso do android, por exemplo, deve existir um arquivo `nome_arquivo_imagem.png` no diretório `\Resources\drawable`*

Comment: Valeu cara, não imaginava que fosse tão simples assim!!

Comment: tu está me ajudando muito, da hora... pois to iniciando agora com com xamarin

Comment: Que maravilha! Pode contar com a ajuda da comunidade, sempre que possível estarei participando!